# Strip consecutive empty lines in a golang writer

Tags: go, writer

I've got a Go text/template that renders a file, however I've found it difficult to structure the template cleanly while preserving the line breaks in the output.

I'd like to have additional, unnecessary newlines in the template to make it more readable, but strip them from the output. Any group of newlines more than a normal paragraph break should be condensed to a normal paragraph break, e.g.

```
lines with



too many breaks should become lines with

normal paragraph breaks.
```

The string is potentially too large to store safely in memory, so I want to keep it as an output stream.

My first attempt:

```
type condensingWriter struct {
    writer io.Writer
    lastLineIsEmpty bool
}

func (c condensingWriter) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error){
    thisLineIsEmpty := strings.TrimSpace(string(b)) == ""
    defer func(){
        c.lastLineIsEmpty = thisLineIsEmpty
    }()
    if c.lastLineIsEmpty && thisLineIsEmpty{
        return 0, nil
    } else {
        return c.writer.Write(b)
    }
}
```

This doesn't work because I naively assumed that it would buffer on newline characters, but it doesn't.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Comment: Perhaps use this Play as a starting point:

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/wNtHFHobhm

Comment: ~100 MB on a very small server.

Comment: Though I don't see why it matters to this question, unless you're going to reply "Don't".

Comment: Note that you have a value receiver, so `c.lastLineIsEmpty = thisLineIsEmpty` won't be observable by the next `Write` call.

Comment: zmb: I don't understand what you mean, can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by zmb's approach, I've come up with the following package:

```
//Package striplines strips runs of consecutive empty lines from an output stream.
package striplines

import (
  "io"
  "strings"
)

// Striplines wraps an output stream, stripping runs of consecutive empty lines.
// You must call Flush before the output stream will be complete.
// Implements io.WriteCloser, Writer, Closer.
type Striplines struct {
  Writer   io.Writer
  lastLine []byte
  currentLine []byte
}

func (w *Striplines) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
  totalN := 0
  s := string(p)
  if !strings.Contains(s, "\n") {
    w.currentLine = append(w.currentLine, p...)
    return 0, nil 
  }
  cur := string(append(w.currentLine, p...))
  lastN := strings.LastIndex(cur, "\n")
  s = cur[:lastN]
  for _, line := range strings.Split(s, "\n") {
    n, err := w.writeLn(line + "\n")
    w.lastLine = []byte(line)
    if err != nil {
      return totalN, err 
    }   
    totalN += n
  }
  rem := cur[(lastN + 1):]
  w.currentLine = []byte(rem)
  return totalN, nil 
}

// Close flushes the last of the output into the underlying writer.
func (w *Striplines) Close() error {
  _, err := w.writeLn(string(w.currentLine))
  return err 
}

func (w *Striplines) writeLn(line string) (n int, err error) {
  if strings.TrimSpace(string(w.lastLine)) == "" && strings.TrimSpace(line) == "" {
    return 0, nil 
  } else {
    return w.Writer.Write([]byte(line))
  }
}
```

See it in action here: http://play.golang.org/p/t8BGPUMYhb

Comment: Nice!  Although `striplines.Striplines` is a poor type name (it stutters).  How about `striplines.Writer`instead?

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is you'll have to look for consecutive newlines anywhere in the input slice and if such cases exist, skip over all but the first newline character.

Additionally, you have to track whether the last byte written was a newline, so the next call to `Write` will know to eliminate a newline if necessary.  You were on the right track by adding a `bool` to your writer type.  However, you'll want to use a pointer receiver instead of a value receiver here, otherwise you'll be modifying a *copy* of the struct.

You would want to change

```
func (c condensingWriter) Write(b []byte)
```

to

```
func (c *condensingWriter) Write(b []byte)
```

You could try something like [this](http://play.golang.org/p/TUDbgfFXUq).  You'll have to test with larger inputs to make sure it handles all cases correctly.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "os"
)

var Newline byte = byte('\n')

type ReduceNewlinesWriter struct {
    w               io.Writer
    lastByteNewline bool
}

func (r *ReduceNewlinesWriter) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    // if the previous call to Write ended with a \n
    // then we have to skip over any starting newlines here
    i := 0
    if r.lastByteNewline {
        for i < len(b) && b[i] == Newline {
            i++
        }
        b = b[i:]
    }
    r.lastByteNewline = b[len(b) - 1] == Newline

    i = bytes.IndexByte(b, Newline)
    if i == -1 {
        // no newlines - just write the entire thing
        return r.w.Write(b)
    }
    // write up to the newline
    i++
    n, err := r.w.Write(b[:i])
    if err != nil {
        return n, err
    }

    // skip over immediate newline and recurse
    i++

    for i < len(b) && b[i] == Newline {
        i++
    }
    i--
    m, err := r.Write(b[i:])
    return n + m, nil
}

func main() {
    r := ReduceNewlinesWriter{
        w: os.Stdout,
    }
    io.WriteString(&r, "this\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhas\nmultiple\n\n\nnewline\n\n\n\ncharacters")
}
```

Comment: You didn't say anything about spaces. "Any group of newlines more than a normal paragraph break should be condensed"

Comment: Although that would be an easy update. Instead of comparing against the Newline var just check for any whitespace.